# reload translation file in pyramid web framework

Tags: translation, pyramid, mo

I develop a translation helper page in my pyramid based application.
A new translation is saved in `.po` and `.mo` files via this:

```
po = polib.pofile(join(root, 'locale', lang, 'LC_MESSAGES', 'myapp.po'))
.....

po.save(join(root, 'locale', lang, 'LC_MESSAGES', 'myapp.po'))
po.save_as_mofile(join(root, 'locale', lang, 'LC_MESSAGES', 'myapp.mo'))
```

But the new translation does not take effect until I restart the application.

I need to reload the translation file right after the new translation file is saved without restarting the wsgi application.

Answer (score 1):

Translations are cached for performance in Pyramid but you can setup pserve to automatically restart the wsgi server when the files change. Just add `watch_files` directive to your ini file. The watcher uses python glob module and so what is supported depends on if you're on python2 or python3 but you can experiment to find a regex that works. (For example, `**` is not supported on python 2).

```
[pserve]
watch_files = myapp/locales/**/*
```